# Replace nulls with 0 in Dynamic Pivot SQL

Tags: sql

I have a dynamic pivot sql that is working as I'd like except I can't figure out where to put the isnull in it to remove the null values from the results. Right now I have some null values in the columns that are outputted that I need to be zero.

Below is the SQL and any help would be greatly appreciated!

```
DECLARE @cols AS NVARCHAR(MAX),
    @query  AS NVARCHAR(MAX)

select @cols = STUFF((SELECT ',' + QUOTENAME(MonthYear) 
                    from temp
                    group by MonthYear, [Year], [Month]
                    order by [Year], [Month]
            FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE
            ).value('.', 'NVARCHAR(MAX)') 
        ,1,1,'')

set @query = 'SELECT Receive_Br, ' + @cols + ' from 
             (
                select Receive_Br, MonthYear, COGS 
                from temp
            ) x
            pivot 
            (
                max(COGS)
                for MonthYear in (' + @cols + N')
            ) p '

execute(@query)
```

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest using `CASE` statement in the select statement on the column that is outputting `Null` values.

Example:

`Case WHEN Column_Name IS NULL THEN 0 ELSE Column_Name END AS Column_Name`

Hope that helps!

Comment: The issue is there are dynamic column names so they are not always the same. I'll need to put an isnull in there somewhere to do it but I'm just not sure where.

Comment: Where exactly will the dynamic column names be referenced in the query?

Answer (score 0):

Declare another variable to hold the columns with `ISNULL` function as the following:

```
select @colsWithIsNull = STUFF((SELECT ', ISNULL(' + QUOTENAME(MonthYear) + ', 0) As ' + QUOTENAME(MonthYear)
                    from temp
                    group by MonthYear, [Year], [Month]
                    order by [Year], [Month]
            FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE
            ).value('.', 'NVARCHAR(MAX)') 
        ,1,1,'')
```

Now use that variable with your query as the following:

```
set @query = 'SELECT Receive_Br, ' + @colsWithIsNull + ' from 
             (
                select Receive_Br, MonthYear, COGS 
                from temp
            ) x
            pivot 
            (
                max(COGS)
                for MonthYear in (' + @cols + N')
            ) p '

execute(@query)
```

See a demo from [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=ad438fa8da0ce76c6baef1ad78645fe3).

Comment: Thank you for advice Ahmed. I can't seem to get it working though, it executes the sql but just says "command completed successfully" without any results. It appears it's just doing the first variable.

Comment: @rothnic, Have you checked the demo, it's working well, note that you should declare two variables for columns, one with `ISNULL` and the other without, in the demo '@valCols and @valCols1`